# 400 Bad Request, RESTTEMPLATE

Tags: java, android, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

Im trying to send restTemplate with long and image data. Im following [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-android-samples/blob/master/spring-android-showcase/client/src/org/springframework/android/showcase/rest/HttpPostFormDataActivity.java) tutorial code and getting next error:

`W/RestTemplate: POST request for "http://192.168.0.250:8081/server/upload" resulted in 400 (Bad Request); invoking error handler
 E/ContentValues: 400 Bad Request org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request`

I have made simply restteamplate for Long data, but here I have some trubles.

Here are my Android client:

```
protected AnotherPostDTO doInBackground(Void... params) {
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("res/drawable/bbb.png");
formData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
formData.add("owners_id", "1");
formData.add("file", resource);

try {
    HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(formData, requestHeaders);

    ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>(Arrays.asList(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(), new FormHttpMessageConverter()));
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(converters);

    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());

    return restTemplate.postForObject(Constants.URLs.UPLOAD_FILE, requestEntity, AnotherPostDTO.class);

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
}
return post;}
```

My server controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "postformdata", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Content-Type=multipart/form-data")
public @ResponseBody String handleFormUpload(@RequestParam("description") String description,
                                             @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        byte[] bytes = null;
        try {
            bytes = file.getBytes();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("taski");
        }
        return "file upload received! Name:[" + description + "] Size:["
                + bytes.length + "]";
    } else {
        return "file upload failed!";
    }
}
```

and bean:

```
@Bean
MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
    MultipartConfigFactory factory = new MultipartConfigFactory();
    factory.setMaxFileSize("128KB");
    factory.setMaxRequestSize("128KB");
    return factory.createMultipartConfig();
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what value is this Constants.URLs.UPLOAD_FILE

Comment: Constants.URLs.UPLOAD_FILE = "http://192.168.0.250:8081/server/upload"

Comment: your contrller method expects a description requestparam  which you are not passing

Comment: Okay, i have failed while copying code into stackoverflow. My method has AnotherPostDTO type. Did you mean this?